# Add and remove operations doesn't work in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository, addition, dbset

I was doing some tests about repository pattern applied to Entity Framework, when a problem comes out.  I have implemented (via code-first) a core-layer and data-layer of an imaginary hotel manager software (called HotelManager) that i'd like to use for testing purposes and that relates with a bunch of table to DB.

This is the structure:

1. The core-layer stays in the HotelManager.Core assembly and contains:

   - All models (autogenerated with "Reverse engineer code first" utility)
   - IRepostiory interface (used for repositories abstraction into core layer)

   .
2. The data-layer stays in the HotelManager.Data assembly and contains:

   - All model mappings (autogenerated with "Reverse engineer code first" utility)
   - All repositories implementations
   - The context (autogenerated with "Reverse engineer code first" utility)
   - The Unit of work that includes all repositories

As you can see, the data-layer exposes an Unit of work class that client applications uses to manipulate data, but here i noticed a strange behavior. In fact all repositories contained into my UoW loads correctly, but  adding and removing operations doesn't work at all!

For example:

```
[TestMethod]
public void AddWontWork()
{
    int firstCount = this._hotelManagerUoW.Utenti.AsEnumerable().Count();
    AddUser();
    int lastCount = this._hotelManagerUoW.Utenti.AsEnumerable().Count();
    Assert.IsTrue(lastCount  == firstCount + 1); 

}

private void AddUser()
{
    Utente utente = new Utente();
    utente.Nome = "Alex";
    utente.Cognome = "DeLarge";
    utente.Indirizzo = "London st.";
    utente.Nazione = "England";
    utente.Password = "mypassword";
    utente.Username = "MyUsername";
    utente.ZipCode = "784521";
    utente.Citta = "Coventry";

    this._hotelManagerUoW.Utenti.Add(utente);
}
```

This test method 'll fail!
I don't know why but even after `AddUser()` method has been called (`AddUser()` actually adds to the `Utenti` repository an instance of a new `utente` object), `lastCount` matches to `firstCount`, like nothing has been happened, and the test fails! I can't even find my brand new added entity into the DbSet managed by my repository! I have the same result when i remove an entity from a repository. Nothing happens. This 'll work only if i call SaveChanges() method after each Add() or Remove() operation but this is not possible, because i need to have the chance to rollback data and because i want to interact with DB only in certain, well-defined cases to reduce DB access the least possible.

Is this the correct behavior of EF and i have completely misunderstood its behavior or there is something wrong in my project?
I always thought that if i run something like `UtentiDbSet.Add(new Utente() with {....});`, EF engine adds my new Utente object to the DbSet in an "Added" state (and so, UtentiDbSet.Count() == 1), and then, if i call SaveChanges() of my context, the data 'll be persisted to DB.

For your convenience i've uploaded whole project [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60231308/HotelManager_Sample.rar).

There's a test project called *HotelManager.Data.Test*.
I can't understand why `AddWontWork()` method fails, while `AddWithSaveChangesWillWork()` works.
Don't forget to set up the connectionString in the app.config of the *HotelManager.Data.Test* project (The EF 'll take care to build the entire DB structure using the mappings contained into the data-layer).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To see what you've added to Utenti you'll need to query the ChangeTracker...

Comment: So, if I add an entity to a dbset, the only way I have to get it is to query the changetracker object? If I iterate directly over the dbset I'll not find nothing except entities already persisted to db?  And how do I implement the classic GetAll() method of a repository? I need to merge the result of the change tracker with the result of .AsEnumerable()? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Your AddUser() code is lacking a context.SaveChanges() call.